# Extracting a React Component that is not available in npm

Tags: reactjs, carbon-design-system

There is a project that contains a React Component and it is in Git so it is publicly available with all its resources, how can I extract just that one component with all its dependencies without having to do it manually by opening each file?

Here is the component in question:

https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-website/tree/master/src/components/ComponentDemo

Comment: Have a look at [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but will these methods also extract the subcomponents needed to support this component? That is where I have having problems because I can clone the whole repo and pick the one component I need but I also have to manually move dependencies.